# How to (quickly) ascertain the subtype in a "Class Table Inheritance" relational database model?

Tags: database, relational-database

Lets say I use class table inheritance in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
   id INT(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   forename VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   surname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE employee
(
   id INT(10) NOT NULL,
   salary INT(10),
   FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES person (id)
);

CREATE TABLE volunteer
(
   id INT(10) NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES person (id)
);
```

Ok, now say I want to check permissions on my site, i.e. I need to check if a person is an employee or a volunteer. I could put a foreign key in 'person' to a 'type' table but surely this introduces a problem because a subtype of an employee could change to a volunteer and this 'type' in the superclass would also need to be updated.

Without this I would have to search for the existance of the id in either table to find its subtype which would be very inefficient. I need a way where I can use a single field to figure out the subtype. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way forward is to use a view.

```
create view persons_all as (
select p.id, p.forename, p.surname, 'employee' as category
from person p
inner join employee e
        on p.id = e.id
union all 
select p.id, p.forename, p.surname, 'volunteer' as category
from person p
inner join volunteer v
        on p.id = v.id
);
```

You can consider shortening that text to "E" for employees and "V" for volunteers.

You should declare the primary keys for "employee" and "volunteer".

There's nothing in your design to prevent the same person from being entered as both an employee and a volunteer. That *might* not be what you intended.